# Angular4 router event NavigationEnd stopped navigation in Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, routes, navigation

In a component, I am subscribing to router event 'NavigationEnd' in 'ngOnInit' as below:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
this.router.events
  .filter((e: {}) => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe((event: {}) => {           
    this.myFunction();
  });
}
```

Along with above code I am using router.navigate([link]) in another component as below:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

public navigateToLink = (link: string): void => {
 this.router.navigate([link]);
}
```

It is working fine in Chrome, but, navigation is not working at all in Firefox, after commenting router event subscription code, router navigation start working in Firefox.
Please guide me what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it doesn't work in firefox but I am using router events with NavigationEnd and this is how I control it.

```
navigation: any;
navigationId: any;
this.routerEvents = _router.events
    .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe((val: Event) => {

        this.navigation = val;
        var currentRoute = this._router.url;
        if (val instanceof NavigationEnd && (this.navigationId === undefined || this.navigationId !== this.navigation.id)) {
            this.navigationId = this.navigation.id;
            //do the thing here
        }
    });
```

Here I am checking if router Event is not getting called multiple times if I am keep visiting this component, events stores the event in a stack so I am calling the inside code only one time.

Also unsubscribe to events on destory

```
ngOnDestroy() {
        if(this.routerEvents){
            this.routerEvents.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh,
Thanks for your quick reply, I am doing the same but it is not working in Firefox.